# Travis reports odd message of corrupted Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby, bundler, travis-ci

Im using bundler to install stuff and since I have added `Gemfile.lock`, travis started to complain with:

```
Your Gemfile.lock is corrupt. The following gem is missing from the DEPENDENCIES
section: 'echoe'
```

Of course, everything works locally. It also works using `DeployBot`. I even installed docker ubuntu and tried, still ok. My `Gemfile.lock` is not corrupt. Same versions of ruby and bundler is used.

What is going on?

#### Update

This is something related to bundler version. Im using 1.11.0, but got reports that it worked with eg. 1.8.3. ??

Comment: Did you forget to commit the new `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: No. Actually this happens after gemfile.lock was committed.

Comment: Sorry @Jordan just updated the question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We've seen a very similar issue today on [Buildkite](https://buildkite.com/) due to the recent release of a new bundler version 
https://rubygems.org/gems/bundler/versions/1.11.0

We got the build working by stipulating the version of bundler to install.

```
gem install -v 1.10.6 bundler --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

and forcing the use of that

```
bundle _1.10.6_ install
```

Comment: Thanx, this really did the trick! I tried to use 1.10.0 but for some reason it faild, but when I put what you said above in my travis.yml, it worked!

Comment: I uninstalled the previous version and installed 1.10.6 and it worked for me. didn't have to force bundler to use a particular version. Thanks.

Comment: @игор, @s01ipsist, can I have a look at how you specified it in your `.travis.yml`. The posted answer is yet to work for me and I think I have used the wrong statement in my travis file.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, remove the gem lock file:

```
rm -f Gemfile.lock
```

Then install the dependencies:

```
bundle install
```

You can update the dependencies to ensure that you won't get an error:

```
bundle update
```

Comment: I've submitted an edit to remove the `-r` flag from `rm`, as this is not required to remove a single file and may encourage the bad practice of using it to remove any files with the greater potential to mistype the command and recursively remove an entire directory.