# Custom code to deploy capistrano without gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ubuntu, deployment, capistrano

So I made an app in windows and I want to deploy it on an ubuntu server with capistrano. Which doesn't work, because "the gemfile.lock is corrupted"

Therefore, I want to do the same thing as Heroku does: delete the gemfile.lock and bundle on the ubuntu server - as I have seen suggested by alot of people.

I've read, here for example: [Corrupt Gemfile.lock Error with Capistrano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604839/corrupt-gemfile-lock-error-with-capistrano), that I should write some custom code

> that deletes Gemfile.lock before the Bundler task runs (or just remove Gemfile.lock from source control entirely). You'd also have to change the Bundler arguments to remove the --deployment flag, otherwise it will fail when it sees the Gemfile.lock is missing.

Can anybody help me with this? I don't understand how to do this... How do I remove Gemfile.lock from source code? Or how do I write this custom code? Where can i find these Bundler arguments?

I suppose this is a stupid question, but please help me, I'm really stuck :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found a guide that solves this: http://corlewsolutions.com/articles/article-10-how-to-deploy-rails-applications-using-capistrano-3-1-and-windows-7

Aditionally, I deleted the platform mentions in my gemfile.lock and it worked like a charm!