# Having trouble deploying rails application on a server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, capistrano, puma

I am having trouble deploying my rails application with puma and capistrano on my server. Also I am using 
https://mattbrictson.com/build-and-deploy-a-rails-vps-part-2 
as a reference guide

But when I try to run `bundle exec cap production deploy` 
I will get the following error message:

```
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deployer@SERVER: bundle exit status: 16
bundle stdout: Your bundle only supports platforms ["x86-mingw32"] but your local platforms are["ruby", "x86_64-linux"], and there's no compatible match between those two lists.
```

Which is strange since when I run: `bundle platform` 
I get:

```
Your platform is: x86_64-linux-gnu

Your app has gems that work on these platforms:
* ruby

Your Gemfile does not specify a Ruby version requirement.
```

And the Gemfile.lock contains the following:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/capistrano/rbenv.git
  revision: 65db3295752d079bf8cf874dab36b16ab45454b7
  specs:
    capistrano-rbenv (2.1.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.0.3)
      actionpack (= 5.0.3)
      nio4r (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.0.3)
      actionpack (= 5.0.3)
      actionview (= 5.0.3)
      activejob (= 5.0.3)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.0.3)
      actionview (= 5.0.3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.3)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.0.3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.3)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activeadmin (1.0.0)
      arbre (>= 1.1.1)
      bourbon
      coffee-rails
      formtastic (~> 3.1)
      formtastic_i18n
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7)
      jquery-rails
      jquery-ui-rails
      kaminari (>= 0.15, < 2.0)
      railties (>= 4.2, < 5.2)
      ransack (~> 1.3)
      sass-rails
      sprockets (< 4.1)
    activejob (5.0.3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.3)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.0.3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.3)
    activerecord (5.0.3)
      activemodel (= 5.0.3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.3)
      arel (~> 7.0)
    activesupport (5.0.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    airbrussh (1.2.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.6.1, != 1.7.0)
    arbre (1.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    arel (7.1.4)
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    bindex (0.5.0)
    bourbon (4.3.4)
      sass (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.19)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (9.0.6)
    capistrano (3.8.1)
      airbrussh (>= 1.0.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.9.0)
    capistrano-bundler (1.2.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-rails (1.2.3)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    capistrano3-puma (3.1.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.7)
      capistrano-bundler
      puma (~> 3.4)
    coffee-rails (4.2.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.2.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    devise (4.3.0)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 5.2)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    formtastic (3.1.5)
      actionpack (>= 3.2.13)
    formtastic_i18n (0.6.0)
    globalid (0.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    haml (5.0.1)
      temple (>= 0.8.0)
      tilt
    has_scope (0.7.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.1, < 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.1, < 5.2)
    i18n (0.8.1)
    inherited_resources (1.7.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.2, < 5.2.x)
      has_scope (~> 0.6)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.2.x)
      responders
    jbuilder (2.6.4)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.3.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    kaminari (1.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.0.1)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.0.1)
      kaminari-core (= 1.0.1)
    kaminari-actionview (1.0.1)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.0.1)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.0.1)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.0.1)
    kaminari-core (1.0.1)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.5)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
    minitest (5.10.2)
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (4.1.0)
    nio4r (2.0.0)
    nokogiri (1.7.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    polyamorous (1.3.1)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    puma (3.8.2)
    rack (2.0.3)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (5.0.3)
      actioncable (= 5.0.3)
      actionmailer (= 5.0.3)
      actionpack (= 5.0.3)
      actionview (= 5.0.3)
      activejob (= 5.0.3)
      activemodel (= 5.0.3)
      activerecord (= 5.0.3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.3)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 5.0.3)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (5.0.3)
      actionpack (= 5.0.3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.3)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.0.0)
    ransack (1.8.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      i18n
      polyamorous (~> 1.3)
    responders (2.4.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
    sass (3.4.24)
    sass-rails (5.0.6)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
        sprockets (3.7.1)
          concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
          rack (> 1, < 3)
        sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
          actionpack (>= 4.0)
          activesupport (>= 4.0)
          sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
        sqlite3 (1.3.13)
        sshkit (1.13.1)
          net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
          net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
        temple (0.8.0)
        thor (0.19.4)
        thread_safe (0.3.6)
        tilt (2.0.7)
        turbolinks (5.0.1)
          turbolinks-source (~> 5)
        turbolinks-source (5.0.3)
        tzinfo (1.2.3)
          thread_safe (~> 0.1)
        tzinfo-data (1.2017.2)
          tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
        uglifier (3.2.0)
          execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
        warden (1.2.7)
          rack (>= 1.0)
        web-console (3.5.1)
          actionview (>= 5.0)
          activemodel (>= 5.0)
          bindex (>= 0.4.0)
          railties (>= 5.0)
        websocket-driver (0.6.5)
          websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
        websocket-extensions (0.1.2)

    PLATFORMS
      ruby

    DEPENDENCIES
      activeadmin
      byebug
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      capistrano-bundler
      capistrano-rails
      capistrano-rbenv!
      capistrano3-puma
      coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
      devise
      haml
      jbuilder (~> 2.5)
      jquery-rails
      puma (~> 3.0)
      rails (~> 5.0.0)
      sass-rails (~> 5.0)
      sqlite3
      turbolinks (~> 5)
      tzinfo-data
      uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
      web-console

    BUNDLED WITH
       1.14.6
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I forget something?

Comment: My guess is that it is because your Gemfile.lock contains `x86-mingw32`. That means you are probably developing on Windows and trying to deploy to Linux? I am not sure how to get that to work :(

Comment: Here is an accepted answer for what I think is the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604839/corrupt-gemfile-lock-error-with-capistrano/35021383#35021383

Comment: Yes I saw that one, but it is not solving the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add ruby version in your Gemfile?

```
ruby '2.3.3' // or whatever your ruby version is
```

Comment: Not solving the problem but I will get the following when I do
~bundle platform

Your platform is: x86_64-linux-gnu

Your app has gems that work on these platforms:
* ruby

Your Gemfile specifies a Ruby version requirement:
* ruby 2.3.3p222