# Linux Remote server cap production deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, deployment, web-deployment

cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as frrank@earth.cloudapp.net: bundle exit status: 20
bundle stdout: Your Gemfile.lock is corrupt. The following gem is missing from the DEPENDENCIES
section: 'bcrypt'
bundle stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 20
bundle stdout: Your Gemfile.lock is corrupt. The following gem is missing from the DEPENDENCIES
section: 'bcrypt'
bundle stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as frrank@earth.cloudapp.net: bundle exit status: 20
bundle stdout: Your Gemfile.lock is corrupt. The following gem is missing from the DEPENDENCIES
section: 'bcrypt'
bundle stderr: Nothing written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to delete your `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install`.
If that will not help try to downgrade the bundler version as in question [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276324/travis-reports-odd-message-of-corrupted-gemfile-lock)

Answer (score 0):

check your bundler version on the production server and local development server.