# Error deploying to Heroku from Windows: says thread_safe is missing but it's there

Tags: ruby, windows, heroku

When I try to deploy to Heroku from Windows, I get this error:

> the following gem is missing from the dependencies section:  thread_safe

Here's the Heroku log:

```
    Counting objects: 75, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (66/66), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (75/75), 17.25 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
    Total 75 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote:
    remote: -----> Ruby app detected
    remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
    remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.2
    remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
    remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/
    bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
    remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
    remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
    remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
    remote:        Installing rake 11.0.1
    remote:        Installing minitest 5.8.4
    remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
    remote:        Your Gemfile.lock is corrupt. The following gem is missing from t
    he DEPENDENCIES
    remote:        section: 'thread_safe'
    remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
    ..........
    remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
    remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
    remote:        Installing rake 11.0.1
    remote:        Installing minitest 5.8.4
    remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
    remote:        Your Gemfile.lock is corrupt. The following gem is missing from t
    he DEPENDENCIES
    remote:        section: 'thread_safe'
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
    remote:  !
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
    remote:
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote:
    remote: !       Push rejected to mighty-thicket-40758.
    remote:
    To https://git.heroku.com/mighty-thicket-40758.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mighty-thicket-40758.
    git'
```

Here's my `Gemfile.lock`, which clearly contains `thread_safe` in the dependencies section:

```
GEM
remote: https://rubygems.org/
specs:
    actionmailer (4.1.8)
    actionpack (= 4.1.8)
    actionview (= 4.1.8)
    mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.8)
    actionview (= 4.1.8)
    activesupport (= 4.1.8)
    rack (~> 1.5.2)
    rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.8)
    activesupport (= 4.1.8)
    builder (~> 3.1)
    erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    activemodel (4.1.8)
    activesupport (= 4.1.8)
    builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.8)
    activemodel (= 4.1.8)
    activesupport (= 4.1.8)
    arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.20)
    activerecord (>= 2.2)
    activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter (1.3.20)
    activerecord-jdbc-adapter (~> 1.3.20)
    jdbc-postgres (>= 9.1)
    activesupport (4.1.8)
    i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
    json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
    minitest (~> 5.1)
    thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    builder (3.2.2)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
    coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
    railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
    coffee-script-source
    execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.4.1)
    activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
    multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jdbc-postgres (9.4.1206)
    jquery-rails (3.1.4)
    railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
    thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3-java)
    mail (2.6.3)
    mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mime-types (2.99.1)
    minitest (5.8.4)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    rack (1.5.5)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
    rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.1.8)
    actionmailer (= 4.1.8)
    actionpack (= 4.1.8)
    actionview (= 4.1.8)
    activemodel (= 4.1.8)
    activerecord (= 4.1.8)
    activesupport (= 4.1.8)
    bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
    railties (= 4.1.8)
    sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
    rails_serve_static_assets
    rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.4)
    railties (4.1.8)
    actionpack (= 4.1.8)
    activesupport (= 4.1.8)
    rake (>= 0.8.7)
    thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (11.0.1)
    rdoc (4.2.2)
    json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.5)
    railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    sass (~> 3.2.2)
    sprockets (~> 2.8, < 3.0)
    sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
    json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
    rdoc (~> 4.0)
    sprockets (2.12.4)
    hike (~> 1.2)
    multi_json (~> 1.0)
    rack (~> 1.0)
    tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
    actionpack (>= 3.0)
    activesupport (>= 3.0)
    sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    therubyrhino (2.0.4)
    therubyrhino_jar (>= 1.7.3)
    therubyrhino_jar (1.7.6)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5-java)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
    coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
    thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2016.1)
    tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uglifier (2.7.2)
    execjs (>= 0.3.0)
    json (>= 1.8.0)

PLATFORMS
java

DEPENDENCIES
activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter
coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
jbuilder (~> 2.0)
jquery-rails
rails (= 4.1.8)
rails_12factor
sass-rails (~> 4.0.3)
sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
therubyrhino
thread_safe
turbolinks
tzinfo-data
uglifier (>= 1.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
1.11.2
```

I know Heroku sometimes [does fancy things with the Gemfile.lock](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile), but I'm not using any Windows-specific gems.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: It would help if you posted the Heroku log showing the error.

Comment: Okay, I've added that.

Comment: May be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276324/travis-reports-odd-message-of-corrupted-gemfile-lock

Comment: I saw this thread and tried using bundler 1.10.6 with no different result, sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" the problem by specifying JRuby as the engine in my Gemfile:

```
ruby '2.2.2', :engine => 'jruby', :engine_version => '9.0.0.0'
```

So I'm still not sure what was happening, just that [the generic Heroku Rails 4.x start guide](http://ruby%20'2.2.2',%20:engine%20=%3E%20'jruby',%20:engine_version%20=%3E%20'9.0.0.0') isn't sufficient for Windows...must rely on [this one](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-jruby#introduction) and dig into their sample app to make your own.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to /config/application.rb
    `config.threadsafe!`
And run
    `bundle update`

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `threadsafe!' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x54acff7d>